# Is this a bug in GMP 4.1.2 or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c, gmp

To this bit of code I pass the string `"kellogs special k"` and I get `1` which means that the string is an integer. What on earth am I doing wrong? Or is it a GMP problem?

```
#define F(x) mpf_t (x); mpf_init( (x) );

long __stdcall FBIGISINTEGER(BSTR p1) {
    USES_CONVERSION;
    F(n1);
    LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );
    mpf_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );
    return mpf_integer_p( n1 );
}
```

By the way, if anyone's going to suggest using a more recent GMP, please can you give me the web address of the static LIB for Windows. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the return value of `mpf_set_str`. It returns `0` on success and `-1` on failure. In this case it would have returned a failure and `n1` is left untouched. `mpf_init` initialized it to zero, so testing whether zero is an integer with `mpf_integer_p` returns true.